# preserve the data while dropping a hive internal table

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have loaded a huge table from SQL Server onto Hive. The mistake I made is I created the table as a Internal table in HIVE. Can anyone suggest any hack so that I can alter the table structure , without dropping the data. 
The data is huge and I cant afford to export the data out of source again.

The problem right now, is that since the column orders don't match the SQL server table, a lot of columns display NULL.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any problem to use an Alter Table on a internal table.  (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/Partition/Column)

Another - but not recommended - option would be to open your hive metastore(HCatalog) and apply the changes there. Hive reads out the schema information from a relational database (configured during the Hadoop setup, default is MySQL). In this MySQL you can try to change some settings. However, this is not recommended as with a mistake, you can screw your whole Hive databases.

The safest way is creating a new table and using the existing as a source

```
create table new_table
as
select
[...]
from existing_table
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks Stefan. I will try to create a copy of the table and move the data in the right order.

Comment: If you want to test your ALTER changes in a sandbox: create a test "EXTERNAL" table "LOCATED" on a test HDFS directory; copy *one* of the physical data files in that directory; then you can do some trial-and-error.

Comment: By the way, an alternate answer to your question would be: create the EXTERNAL table w/ exactly the same structure but LOCATED in a different directory, then move all physical files to that directory. The original table is now "empty", you can drop it at leisure.